# Could not edit /etc/hosts file, is there any user specific config file which does same?

Tags: linux

I do not have root permissions to edit /etc/hosts. So is it possible to have user specific `/etc/hosts` which lies inside users home dir (user has permissions to edit) and which routes the `url` correctly in web browser or while doing ssh?

Comment: Please describe a bit more what you're trying to accomplish instead of just describing what you've done.

Comment: No, there is not. See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10438/can-i-create-a-user-specific-hosts-file-to-complement-etc-hosts). Like @SamiLaine said, you need to describe what your problem is and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @sami: hey given more info.

Comment: For SSH there's `~/.ssh/config`, as for the browser, what browser? You could also use some sort of a proxy.